# Does \s shorthand match newlines in PHP regex?

Tags: php, regex, expression

Can `\s` match newlines or should I use the `/s` pattern modifier to make the `.` match newlines?
I don't want the regex to match 'anything'. Instead I want it to match just newlines/spaces.

Comment: `\s` matches newlines, see this [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dY0cH6/1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/#pcre) `\s`:

> Matches any space, tab or newline character.

So yes, but it's not exactly what you are asking for. But it is a lot closer than using `.`, which has a tendency to cause catastrophic backtracking and general inefficiency.

If you want to *just* match spaces and new lines, you can use:

```
[ \n\r]
```

Comment: `.` has *nothing* to do with catastrophic backtracking, which is caused by nested quantifiers. It's also *far* from being inefficient (unless used improperly of course).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Beginners have the most trouble with efficiency, and I often see `.` used where `[^something]` or `[something]` should be used instead. That's what I meant by "tendency". Of course, as an expert, you should be able to know how to use `.` without an issue.